# Android root directory in centos 6

Tags: android, centos, centos6

I've installed eclipse, ADT plugin for it and I get an error "Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences". I go to preferences but I can't find the root directory of android SDK. Where is it?

edit:
I've set the location to the preferences. Now I get the error 'Android SDK Content Loader' has encountered a problem parseSdkContent failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded the SDK starter package from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)? If not download to a directory of your choice and then point Eclipse to that directory.

Comment: I've downloaded it, and set the location to the preferences. Now I get the error 'Android SDK Content Loader' has encountered a problem parseSdkContent failed

Comment: Look at the answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019051/problem-with-android-sdk-content-loader