# Android sdk Content Loader has encountered an issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I got an error message when I start eclipse.

"**Android sdk Content Loader has encountered a problem**.

**parseSdkContent failed**"

" *parseSdkContent failed*

*java.lang.NullPointerException* "

What I can do now?
I can't get AVD manager to start emulator. I can't get SDK manager also....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019051/android-sdk-content-loader-failing-with-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's so **Easy**:

1. Delete your "C:\Users\ [username] \ .android\avd"
2. Delete all AVD
3. Restart eclipse and
4. start AVD manager

**Done**

Answer (score 5):

'Android SDK Content Loader' has encountered a problem - parseSdkContent failed
After install fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Eclipse ADT with Android SDK, 'Android SDK Content Loader' has encountered a problem of parseSdkContent failed, Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface.

[image]

To fix it, delete Android L (API 20, L preview) in Android SDK Manager and restart Eclipse. It work in my case. Even re-install Android L (API 20, L preview).

Taken from, http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-sdk-content-loader-has.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the ***your-avd-name.ini (config files)*** that is located at .android (Search it in windows search) on your Windows machine (if you’re Windows user). When any error occurs during the avd.ini parser, the Google ADT plugin tries to access a map that is null. ***The workaround is to delete the offending .ini file and recreate your avd(s).***

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem once. I fixed it by removing all the android virtual devices I created.
By clicking on Android Virtual Device Manager you will see all the virtual devices created.