# parseSdkContent failed java.lang.NullPointerException. after bsod

Tags: android-virtual-device

I got an error with Android SDK Content Loader

`has encountered a problem.  parseSdkContent failed  java.lang.NullPointerException`

After bsod.. I have tried to delete the avd folders and .ini files. The SDK is working properly again. But, the problems were the avd folders that i have backup cannot be restored since when i restored them, the problems started occuring again. Is there any way to get my avd data again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019051/android-sdk-content-loader-failing-with-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

C: -> Users -> [abc] -> Delete .android folder