# parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, nullpointerexception

When I open  layout editor, *eclipse* is giving this error:

```
parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
```

And when I try to run project, it is giving this error :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching myapp".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Every time I'm getting this error and I have to restart eclipse. Is there any solution? This problem started suddenly today.

---

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66000000"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_match_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_detay_lay_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/app_detail_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_detail"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/app_remove_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/app_detail_button"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_remove" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error picture:
[image]

Comment: Does this happen on any new projects or just this one?

Comment: Have you recently updated the SDK tools, or ADT plugin, if so, check there are no updates for both again

Comment: This happens only in this project and I did not update anything. Fortunately it's fixed for now.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I deleted the `home/.android` folder and everything is normal now.

In *Windows* you can find this folder in `C:/Users/User/`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883841/3681056

Note: it happens when you have 2 versions of SDK and eclipse, both in the same computer (and using the same .android file), if you open on version the other will get this error.

Comment: and don't forget to restart the eclipse :)

Comment: If you have an application that uses the maps, that will get broken on deleting the .android folder. The map window will display just a blank screen with the zoom icons.

Comment: Be careful, though - your .android folder contains your AVDs, debug keystore, and more.  You might want to move it somewhere else, instead.

Comment: On Mac, the folder can be found at `~/.android`

Comment: Just remove ~/.android/avd  instead of removing complete folder. It worked for me.  You need to delete the .ini file of the AVD.

Then restart eclipse will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting ".android" is temporarily fixing the problem with me as after sometime it begins to come again ..

Here is another cause and fix that might help .. This is happening because of existence of 2 versions of SDK in the same machine but in case you have only one version (probably it is 21) just download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W) as there is a problem in 21's "layoutlib.jar"). start applying the following:

- Close Eclipse
- Navigate to your sdk folder (something like C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)
- Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder and rename layoutlib.jar (for backup only)
- Copy the same file (layoutlib.jar) from your android-20 folder to this folder "android-21"
- Start Eclipse

Comment: This fixed my problems.

Answer (score 2):

deleting home/.android is useless, i delete ~/.android/avd it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error too

parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

But I could only resolve it after changing my Eclipse ADT from 64 bit to 32 bit on Windows 7 64 bit OS.

Comment: I guess it is related to 5.0 SDK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829679/parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typeface-in