# parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Tags: android

parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

am getting this error often when i open a new project or run a project,or open a project.

Comment: I just hit the same error on a Windows 64-bit Eclipse + ADT bundle installation that I downloaded yesterday.  All the Google hits I've seen for this exact error message have been since June 29, 2014, which makes me think it's a bug only in the newest version of ADT. Do you think downloading an older version would solve it?

Comment: i dono but,in the older versions in which i was using ,i dint get these sorts problem ...this is the first time getting like this errors often ,struck with this errors....but no solution yet,.........if i clear a error fron google,the next error occurs like parse sdk cont failed java.lang.exception.initializationerror.

Comment: I think these questions relate to the same Eclipse bug:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636393/an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching-myapp-java-lang-nullpointerexcep
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683482/eclipse-android-sdk-content-loader

Answer (score 12):

from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77726#c15:

> 1. Download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W)
> 2. Navigate to your sdk folder (should be like
>      D:\EclipseWorkspace\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)
> 3. Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder
> 4. rename layoutlib.jar (for backup purpose)
> 5. copy the same file (layoutlib.jar) from your android-20 folder to this folder
> 6. restart Eclipse

Comment: This is the right solution, seems like there is a problem with the layoutlib.jar in v21...

Answer (score 11):

This errors (parse sdk content failed /graphics,nullpoint exception,initiallization)occurs only when we install Android L packages in sdk,on my occasion.So just try in deleting the Android L packages,and install the lower version to that Android 4.4w.
This process fixed me a solution.

thank you.....

Comment: Same with me. This answer should be accepted if OP found this useful.

Answer (score 3):

delete ~/.android

that seemed to work for me after restarting eclipse

Comment: Suggestions to delete items that don't provide an explanation for what is being deleted and why there is a reason to believe that this is the proper solution are dangerous.

Comment: Don't delete it, you'll stuck

Answer (score 1):

I found after much trial and error that the easiest/safest way for me to fix this problem was by NOT deleting the entire ~/.android which has a bunch of unrelated but important data in it potentially, but by removing the directory(ies) in the ~/.android/avd directory.    I had created a Nexus 7 AVD prior to attempting to use the GUI editor and that's when the parseSDKContent error started showing up.   Removing the directory which in my case was in ~/.android/avd/Nexus7-AVD.avd cleared up the bug and allowed me to edit my activity in the graphical editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the Android target of your project as Android 4.4w (API 20). You can do this in Project->Properties->Android.
This might solve the problem.

Comment: 4.4W API 20 is for wearables. Most likely you should set it to 19 or 21

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using Android API 21 as the target API and I got that problem when I open a xml file or some IDE options.

I solved the problem updating the installed software in the Android SDK Manager. I am not sure if updating all installed software is necessary or only the API 21 SDK Platform, but I have installed all avaible updates and it solved my problem.