# Eclipse: Android SDK content Loader

Tags: android, sdk, loader

Everytime I **start a new project** on Eclipse, this happens:

**`parseSdkContent failed`**

**`Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface`**

what do i have to do to resolve this issue ? I have all the suggested plugins and all that from this page https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me today, what worked for me was deleting the .android folder in `C:/Users/user`.  Good luck!

Comment: What if someone using eclipse on mac?

Answer (score 0):

delete C:/Users/user[.android] is useful temporarily,when you restart Eclipse,it comes again!