# Eclipse - parseSdkContent failed error - not recognizing XML Files

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, windows

I am using Android SDK Tools 23.0.2 with Android API 20 (L preview).

I have been having this error for some time:

> parseSdkContent failed
>   .androidjava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

and I have looked at many other similar questions and tried their solutions to no avail.

They recommended deleting the /.android file in the user directory where my workspace is saved and restarting Eclipse. However this did not work for me.

[parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636393/parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typeface)

[Android SDK Content Loader failing with NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019051/android-sdk-content-loader-failing-with-nullpointerexception/5883841#5883841)

This error seems to be affecting my java code's ability to recognize the XML files it references. When I reference variables to components in the XML file, it does not recognize its existence, even though everything seems to be set up correctly.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: I'm having same issue, tried everything for last 2 days, like changing  java version to 6-7 & 7-6, 7.45-7.65, jdk to oracle java, removing other java versions, eclipse juno, eclipse kepler, download and use new latest adt bundle, creating new user on ubuntu, ubuntu update etc. Please help anyone able to solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

I'd add a comment, but my rep isn't high enough...

Anyway, deleting .android folder worked for me.  Your wording suggests you deleted then restarted Eclipse.  Try:

1. Stop/Exit out of Eclipse
2. Delete .android
3. Restart Eclipse

Comment: Which .android folder? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

I was using the 64 bit version of Eclipse ADT from this link https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

and it was giving me issues on Windows 7 64 bit

I have now downloaded 32 bit version of Eclipse ADT from this link https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

and now its working perfectly.

It might help others too.

Answer (score 1):

I used the "switch workspace" option and created a completely new workspace. This new workspace gives me no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment, but my rep isn't high enough... (just copied and paste here)

I was in the same problem and using Eclipse Luna + ADT Plugin, what I did was:

1. Exit Eclipse.
2. Delete .android folder from my home directory.
3. Delete .metadata folder from my workspace directory.
4. Also in my workspace deleted a folder called .remote (I don't remember exactly what was it's name, just deleted it).
5. Open eclipse, complete the ADT dialog, setup the Android SDK path, and check for eclipse updates.
6. If updates were done better you restart Eclipse before continuing.
7. Import my existing projects, (or create a new one).
8. Open a layout file (xml) to see if the error is gone.

Good luck!

Comment: I lost my project due you'r solution :(

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you miss read, I don't see where it says "delete your project" or "delete your workspace". Good luck!