# fail to start android emulator after update sdk to 23.0.5

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I cannot start my emulator after update sdk to 23.0.5 with following errors on windows.
Can anyone help? thank you

> WARNING : No started emulators found, starting an emulator. Waiting
>   for emulator... emulator: device fd:61HAX is working and emulator runs
>   in fast virt mode emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
>
> creating window 28 27 320 480
>
> FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:89:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1044 max1024 Error accepting connection, aborting

Comment: Did you check congihuration of you AVD? Check "Target" & "CPU/ABI"

Comment: Just to add, same problem here. Really screwing me at a very wrong time...

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503029/15541

Comment: I think that you may use a "Host GPU" option in emulator's parameters. Try to disable it. Or if you required to use proxy settings in the emulator, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31073802/1268291

Answer (score 10):

Start it from the command line:

```
emulator -avd <device_name> -no-audio
```

Comment: Your answer helped. I was able to keep the http proxy by just adding the "-no-audio". Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work for everybody - please star bug so we can get it fixed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=102361

Answer (score 3):

Same here, it seems to be related to http proxy (on command line -http-proxy, or as environment variable http_proxy), **if I don't use http proxy it works**.

Comment: Removing http_proxy env variable worked for me. Since I use Eclipse and AVD manager instead of command line, I had to restart Eclipse and AVD manager after removing http_proxy. And also, checking "Wipe user data" in the Start options helped, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "**-http-proxy none**" (without quotes) in Run configuration **also** fixes this issue as shown in image  attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Related to this thread: [Android emulator with proxy settings - Error FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/ Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1404 max1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484133/android-emulator-with-proxy-settings-error-fatal-android-base-sockets-chec/31254799#31254799)

It still doesn't work. Please star this bug report so we can get it fixed - I already suggested to modify FD_SETSIZE from winsock.h to higer value e.g. 2048 as it doesn't change windows socket implementation as per microsoft's documentation:

```
// Default FD_SETSIZE is 64 which is not enough for us.
#  define FD_SETSIZE 1024
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=102361

Answer (score 0):

**Found another solution:**

You can now use the new Android Emulator 2.0 **Beta** that has the [defect fix](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/170270/).

The defect workarounds (-no-audio -http-proxy none) didnt work for me.

**Get Android Emulator 2.0 Beta:** 
By downloading the new "Android SDK tools" version 25.x.x .
Full instructions can be found **[here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator)**.

Answer (score -1):

I hit this today, and deactivating proxy (or audio, as suggested in another recent question) made no difference. It affected all my AVDs. When I first opened the AVD Manager I was also getting the following error:

```
  Android SDK Content Loader
  parseSdkContent failed
  Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
```

Following the advice from [parseSdkContent failed Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636393/parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typeface) to:

- shutdown eclipse
- delete the `.android` directory (and all contents) in my home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\<your user name>` on Windows 7)
- restart Eclipse

worked a treat for me.